# Declaring a master controller on a state with Angular UI router's $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, url-routing, angular-ui-router

I've just started playing around with UI router, mainly because of the ability to declare nested states and named views.

Here is a simplified example of how I have configured a combination of the two:

```
$stateProvider.state("page", {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "page.html"
})
.state("page.stream", {
  url: "/stream",
  controller: "StreamCtrl",
  views: {
    content: {
      templateUrl: "stream-content.html"
    },
    header: {
      templateUrl: "stream-header.html"
    }
  }
})
.state("page.notifications", {
  url: "/notifications",
  controller: "NotifsCtrl",
  views: {
    content: {
      templateUrl: "notifs-content.html"
    },
    header: {
      templateUrl: "notifs-header.html"
    }
  }
})
```

I have declared the `page` view to be abstract because it's only purpose is to hold two other views, the variable `header` and `content`, alongside navigation which is static across pages.

```
<!-- page.html -->
<nav>...</nav>
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

The routing and plugging in templates works as expected, the navigation stays static when navigating to `/stream` or `/notifications`, and the header and content views change. However, the controller declared on `page.stream` and `page.notifications` does not get initiated.

My first intuition would be that declaring a controller alongside a state configuration's views object would result in the controller beging set on the entire page, so that the header and content would share the controller's `$scope`.

Declaring the controller on the `page` state achieves this, but using `controllerProvider` does not give me access to enough information to decide which controller to use:

```
$stateProvider.state("page", {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "page.html",
  controllerProvider: function ($stateParams) {
    // How do I know which state I am in, notifications or stream?
    return ???
  }
})
```

I have tried to play around with the different notation (absolute/relative) when declaring the view names, and I had some luck with the following:

```
$stateProvider.state("page.stream", {
  url: "/stream",
  views: {
    // I understand that this targets the parent page which holds both header and content
    "@": {
      controller: "StreamController"
    },
    page: {...}
    header: {...}
  }
})
```

This does indeed set the StreamController on the entire page, but results in both of the templates being missing, as if `page.html` was never loaded.

Where should I set the controller on each of my page sub-states so that each view in the sub-state shares the $scope of the controller?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to initialize the controllers as well. You can have stream.html and notifs.html and ng-include templates. I can see how it can be annoying if the page is mixed with common and uncommon portions

```
 .state("page", {
   abstract: true,  
   controller: 'PageCtrl'     
   templateUrl: 'page.html',    
  })
.state("page.stream", {
  url: "/stream",
  controller: 'StreamCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'stream.html'  
})
.state("page.notifications", {
  url: "/notifications",
  controller: 'NotifsCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'notifs.html'
  })


<!-- page.html -->
<nav>...</nav>
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- stream.html-->
<span>stream-header</span>
<div ng-include='"commonthings.html"'></div>
<span>stream-content.html</span>

<!-- notifs.html-->
<span>notifs-header</span>
<div ng-include='"commonthings.html"'></div>
<span>notifs-content.html</span>
```

Each controller initializes correctly

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for trying to instantiate multiple views in a single state is the following. (You must include the controller with each view).

```
.state("page.notifications", {
  url: "/notifications",
  views: {
    content: {
      templateUrl: "notifs-content.html",
      controller: "NotifsCtrl"
    },
    header: {
      templateUrl: "notifs-header.html"
      controller: "NotifsHeaderCtrl"
    }
  }
})
...
```

If you're looking for a controller to be included in both `/stream` and `/notifications` then just include it in your `page` state.

```
$stateProvider.state("page", {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "page.html",
  controller: "PageCtrl"
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't give me what I need -- I would like a `PageCtrl` in the sense that you've described, yes, so that it can control both the header and the content view, but I need this controller to be dynamic -- `NotifsCtrl` when on `page.notifications` and `StreamCtrl` when on `page.stream`.